# Reduce alert view coding

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode6

All.
In my iOS app.
On many pages I am having ***`Too many alerts and also with many Network conditions.`***

With too many alert texts I am fed up.
And Every time I have to put the same code.

Can I declare this Code in Some Helper Class ?
Or Reuse this Code ?

```
-(BOOL)checkInternetAndlocationServices {

    if(IS_INTERNET) {
        if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] &&
           [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Location services are disabled.");
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location services are off." message:@"This app requires an Location services." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Location Services", nil];
            [alert setTag:NO_LOCATIONSERVICES];
            [alert show];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet connection is off." message:@"This app requires an internet connection and locations services, please enable internet connection and location services." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
        [alert setTag:NO_INTERNET];
        [alert show];
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Thanks. 
Please edit this question, if you found it useful..

Thanks for giving good approaches, still any other ways, examples are most welcome.

Comment: Make a `UIAletView` custom subclass.

Comment: Ya, that's what I am also thinking. I have heard/seen about shared object, like people use it as AppDelegate, and CoreDataController as a shared object, Can I use it in this way.

Comment: Meanwhile I am making this as subclass, and making a method of different types, for different types of alerts.

Comment: But how do I call this methods. Can I call them as Singleton object :P

Comment: You have to alloc and initialize customAlertView

Comment: I think singleton object or shared object is not good approach for this problem.

Comment: Singletons are certainly not always evil, but as you mention you have to be careful about thread safety http://stackoverflow.com/a/6810002/3976183

Comment: I would not recommend subclassing as there are far better approaches at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an NSObject class and write method whether Instance or Class method like this and pass only the message and the delegate whether needs to set nil or self like this:-

```
 +(void)showAlertViewWithAlertMessage:(NSString*)alertMessage withDelegate:(id)delegate
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:alertMessage delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:OK_TAP otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

You can use it like this:-
        [Classname showAlertViewWithAlertMessage:@"your message" withDelegate:nil];

Comment: Actually, alert messages will be in this method only, thinking that for network alerts I will call one method, for other types I will call different methods, Do not want to pass messages. Because It looks code so messy.

Comment: So you can use it as this type like :-   +(void)showAlertViewWithAlertMessage
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Network Alert" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }   [Classname showAlertViewWithAlertMessage]

Comment: Ya this is good, I can remove message from here, and put it in the Class, I think it will be good.

Comment: Because I want to give condions also, I will select this as a answer thanks.

Comment: will there be any problem If I call it as a Static method ?

Comment: No there will no issue in that.

Answer (score 5):

1. You could make a helper class and use class methods to show alert.
2. You could also make a UIAlertView category and make a class method for showing alert.**(Edit)**

   ```
    
   @implementation UIAlertView (MyAlert)
   +(void) showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message {
   [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
   }
   @end
   ```
3. You could define a macro in .pch file or some helper header file for showing alert.

   ```
   #define Alert(title,msg,target) [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:target cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show]
   Alert(@"This is Title",@"This is message",self);
   ```

Comment: did you mean helper class like ashForIos mentioned in his answer ?? below

Comment: 3rd one has disadvantage like, we could not define delegate clearly. and need to pass everything to macro. So...

Comment: 1st one and second one please give me examples, so that I can implement it in a better way.

Comment: @ArpitParekh, to your second comment, yes I meant like ashForIos's answer. You can use the similar method by defining category and it will work without have to use another class.

Comment: @ArpitParekh, As far as the disadvantage to macro goes. 
1. You can hardcode any argument directly without having to explicitly pass any parameters.
2. The target you are passing is there to help you with your delegate problem.

Comment: @ArpitParekh, Maybe you will find the Edit useful.

Comment: Actually I need two mottos, 1. Reduce coding of alert view and 2. also I want include conditions. Opposite to Reuse is a wrong word in question title.

Comment: To reduce you can simple hardcode everything, the more static the less the coding, the more dynamic the more the coding.